Simplicial maps determined by their vertex maps.
I want to prove the following.

Let $K$ and
$L$ be simplicial complexes. Suppose $f_0:K_0 \to L_0$ is any map with the property
that whenever $\{v_0, \ldots,v_k\}$ are the vertices of a simplex of $K$, then $\{f_0(v_0),\ldots,f_0(v_k)\}$
are the vertices of a simplex of $L$ (possibly with repetitions). Then there is a unique
simplicial map $f:|K| \to |L|$ whose vertex map is $f_0$. It is a simplicial isomorphism if and only if $f_0$ is a bijection satisfying the following additional condition:
$\{v_0,\ldots,v_k\}$ are the vertices of a simplex of $K$ if and only if $\{f_0(v_0),\ldots,f(v_k)\}$ are
the vertices of a simplex of L.

Above, $K_0$ and $L_0$ denote the $0$-skeleta of $K,L$, i.e. the set of vertices in $K$, $L$.
My attempt: If we we restrict $f_0|_{\text{ver}(\sigma)}$ to the vertices of the $k$-simplex $\sigma \in K$, then the image must be the vertices of $L$. We can now extend $f_0|_{\text{ver}(\sigma)}$ to the interior of $\sigma$, $\text{Int}(\sigma)$ by letting $f|_{\text{Int}(\sigma)}\left(\sum_i t_iv_i \right) := \sum_i t_if(v_i)$ where $t_i > 0$ for all $i = 0,\ldots,k$ and $\sum_i t_i = 1$. Then the image will be in the interior of $\text{Int}(\tau)$ for some simplex $\tau \in L$. We do this for all $0$ to $m$, where $m$ is the integer indexing the maximal $k$-skeleton (there is a maximal $k$-skeleton for every euclidian simplicial complex, I believe, so this is well-defined). We note that for any $k$-simplex $\sigma$, we have that $$\sigma = \bigcup\limits_{\tau \leqslant \sigma} \text{Int}(\sigma)$$ where $\tau \leqslant \sigma$ means that either $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$ or $\sigma$ itself. But then we have that the polyhedron of $K$, $|K| = \bigcup\limits_{\sigma \in K} \sigma$ can be written as $$|K| = \bigcup\limits_{\tau \leqslant \sigma \ \text{for} \ \sigma \in K} \text{Int}(\tau),$$
and $\text{Int}(\tau)$ are open in $|K|$ (I believe). Therefore, $$\Gamma = \{\text{Int}(\tau) \;|\; \tau \leqslant \sigma \ \text{for some $\sigma \in K$}\}$$ is a cover of $|K|$. By an argument given in @davidlowryduda:s answer here (the second paragraph) the interiors are disjoint so there is no overlap, and $f_0$ is linear (so continuous) on each interior $\text{Int}(\sigma)$.
By the above reasoning, we can apply the gluing lemma to get a unique continuous map $f:|K| \to |L|$ such that $f|_{\text{Int}(\sigma)} = f_{0}|_{\text{Int}(\sigma)}$, and so indeed it also restricts down to equal $f_0$ on the vertex set of each $k$-simplex $\sigma \in K$.
If $f$ is a bijection, then I think one can explicitly define $f^{-1}:|L| \to |K|$ as $f^{-1}(\sum_i s_if(v_i)) := \sum_i s_iv_i$, and this is also linear (so continuous), and it is straightforward to check that it is an inverse of $f$.
Is this correct (in rough outlines)?
